# It returns multiplying values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to display the Location and the number of values it returns.

Instead of (a.LOCATION = 2) + (b.LOCATION = 4) = 6

It returns (a.LOCATION = 2) + (b.LOCATION = 4) = 8

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.LOCATION, COUNT(b.LOCATION) AS COUNT
FROM TABLE1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 b
ON a.LOCATION = b.LOCATION GROUP BY a.Location
```

| LOCATION | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| MANILA | 8 |
| SINGAPORE | 6 |

it happens like this

MANILA (a.LOCATION = 4 ) (b.LOCATION = 2 ) = 8

it should be

MANILA (a.LOCATION = 4 ) (b.LOCATION = 2 ) = 6

please help me thanks

EDIT:

TABLE1

| ID | LOCATION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MANILA |
| 2 | MANILA |
| 3 | MANILA |
| 4 | MANILA |
| 5 | SINGAPORE |
| 6 | SINGAPORE |
| 7 | SINGAPORE |
| 8 | SINGAPORE |
| 9 | SINGAPORE |
| 10 | SINGAPORE |

TABLE 2

| ID | LOCATION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MANILA |
| 2 | MANILA |

Comment: you have to provide sample data

Comment: Hello, I edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is to aggregate *before* joining.  Another is to use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select location, count(*)
from ((select a.location from table1 a) union all
      (select b.location from table2 b)
     ) ab
group by location;
```

Note:  This includes all locations that are in either table, even those that are only in `table2`.  I am guessing that this is a good thing.  Your version only includes locations in `table1`.  If you need that logic, it is pretty simply to modify this query to do that.

Comment: Hello, I edited my post. Thank you for the answer

Comment: @bjhayeyy . . . This answer should be doing what you want.